# find sum between two cells if the argument is true

Tags: excel

I have some tables but i need find answer based on the values between two cells
if the first condition is true not need go to second condition

```
IF(B2>K2,E2/24*(C2-B2)/30.41666)
IF(B2<K2,E2/24*C2-K2/30.41666)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just nest the second `IF()` inside the [false] condition of the first `IF()`:

`IF(B2>K2,E2/24*(C2-B2)/30.41666,IF(B2<K2,E2/24*C2-K2/30.41666))`